# How to get the last digit of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript, i want to get the last digit of a string. The following is my code,

```
var idval = focused.id;
var lastChar1 = idval.substr(idval.length - 1);
```

Suppose myid name is **idval5** means, it correctly returns **5**

But if id name is **idval21** means, it is returning **1** only. But i want **21** as a output.

Please anyone help

Comment: Is the digit always at the very end, or so you want to find the last digit appearing anywhere in the string?

Comment: Also: http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: Thanks. Digit always will be at end of the string only.

Comment: Something like this? `(\d+)$`

Comment: const digits = yourString.split('').filter(item => !isNaN(item));
if (digits.length > 0) {
    console.log(digits[digits.length - 1));
}

Answer (score 5):

You could use a regular expression which searches for digits and for the end of the string.

```js
function getLastDigits(s) {
    return s.match(/\d+$/)[0];
}

console.log(['idval2', 'idval21'].map(getLastDigits));
```